# Force internet connection attempt?

Tags: android, connection

I have a service which polls every hour attempts to sync data automatically to the web from the device.

I have it working but I need to find a way to establish an internet connection if there is not one available.

For example - If my phone is in standby mode (screen locked for a period of time) the internet connection is dropped and it is unable to sync when it needs to.

I would like to attempt to connect via wifi if available, then using 3G if required.
Is there a reliable way to do this?

UPDATE - 
I found an article online which uses this code to attempt connection via 3G if there is no wifi available :

```
int resultInt = connectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableHIPRI");
```

unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on all devices, maybe I need to try other options than "enableHIPRI" ??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, although I haven't been able to solve this problem I have discovered that the main cause for the delay in between sync attempts is because the cpu gets stopped during sleep mode, this means my timer task was paused..

My workaround was to rewrite the service using a wakeful intent to get around the timer issue.

This makes my solution much more reliable so I am closing this question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do most of that using [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). It allows you to query the available types of networks and using requestRouteToHost you should be able to ensure there's a connection set up that you need for syncing.

Comment: thanks for the pointer - I found this article which suggests requestRouteToHost does not instantiate a connection attempt :

http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/8dd0c6ebea736dd0/2d143d2121066a48?lnk=raot&pli=1

I need to find a way to attempt a new connection if there is not one already established :)

Comment: Couldn't you just kick off a connection? If it fails you'd get a IOException of some sorts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am recording the last sync time on the web server and I can see that even though it is set to initiate a connection every hour it is sometimes 3 days between activity.  I am testing this at home where I have an available wireless point and 3G access so I have concluded that when the phone is in standby mode it drops the connections and they need to be manually established first - I just cannot find a reliable way to try and establish a manual connection!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot rely on such thing on mobile phone, as in any embedded device you cannot be sure if the device will connect and stay connected when you want. You can only leave a message for the user that data was not synchronized or try to minimize it by checking if there is connection and then synchronizing not just in one hour.

Comment: thanks for the advice but I am not trying to rely on the connection, just rely on attempting a connection regardless of device on wifi then mobile data.  It is not critical if the sync happens every time but it is critical that it attempt to start a connection if there is one available :)